# Excel formula to compare values in 2 different sheets and paste data from another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to compare data between 2 sheets and paste data from another column if there a match.
For example sheet1:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| ID | data |
| 2 | 21 |
| 3 | 34 |
| 4 | 46 |

Sheet2:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| data |  |
| 21 |  |
| 34 |  |
| 46 |  |

So I need to compare data from Sheet1 Column2 with data from Sheet2 Column1 and if they match it would paste the data from Sheet1 Column1 into Sheet2 Column2.
So in Sheet2 Column2 the row with nr 21 should show nr 2 etc.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See ["What Have You Tried?"](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) for an excellent article that you may be interested to read. Thanks.

Comment: I only asked for a direction, of course I have googled and tried multiple things myself.
Such as =INDEX('Sheet1'!$A$2:$B$4,MATCH(Sheet2A2:B4,$A$2:$B$4,0),'Sheet11'!A2:B4) and gave me #N/A result. I also looked into VLOOKUP but same result.

Comment: @user245255 have you tried anyone of the following solutions, i shared down below, i hope it should work for you, if not then please let me know, i shall try to help you out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried any one of the following, you need to change the range accordingly with your data

1.) Formula used in cell E3 applicable to Excel 2021 & O365 Users

`=XLOOKUP($D3,$B$3:$B$5,$A$3:$A$5,"Not Found")`

2.) Formula used in cell F3 `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$5,MATCH($D3,$B$3:$B$5,0)),"Not Found")`

3.) Formula used in cell G3

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D3,CHOOSE({1,2},$B$3:$B$5,$A$3:$A$5),2,0),"Not Found")`

This requires CTRL SHIFT ENTER

4.) Formula used in cell H3 `=IFERROR(LOOKUP($D3,$B$3:$B$5,$A$3:$A$5),"")`

[image: FOUR ALTERNATIVE FORMULAS]